How to Query data while adding a hyperlink at the end of each entry that links to the source?
I have an already functioning simple query function that pulls from several different sheets. I was looking into whether I could add something to the function to append a link to a specific cell of each row.
Currently it looks like so (mildly edited):
=Query(Sheet1!A2:L;Sheet2!A2:L;...;Sheet11!A2:L)

This tab only contains that query, so I wouldn't think a script would apply since I don't need that functionality on any other tabs, or at least I would think it would be more complicated to implement. I've toyed around with lambda and arrayformula, and while the former adds the #gid value as intended, it isn't hyperlinked, and the latter won't parse since its only expecting one argument, unless my syntax just isn't correct.
=Query(ByRow(ExampleSheet!A2:L,LAMBDA(a,{a,"#gid=1910355221&range=H"&ROW(a)})))

Is adding the reference but they don't link, and when I try to add the hyperlink function to the argument it either does nothing or causes an error.
What would be the correct way to embed the functions to provide the desired functionality, if this is even on the right track? And would there be an easier way to implement this, both generally and since I would have to apply this for every sheet that is being queried?
Edit:
Link to sheet to show what outcome I'm looking for
I would want the expected outcome to add the links automatically when it queries if possible, and ideally in a more visually appealing manner.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ, reduce(wraprows(,4,),I1:index(I:I,match(,0/(I:I<>""))),lambda(a,c,{a;let(Λ,indirect(c&"!A:C"),{Λ,index(hyperlink("#gid="&offset(c,,1)&"range=C"&sequence(rows(Λ))))})})),
 sort(filter(Σ,index(Σ,,1)<>""),2,1))



Column_I hosts the tab name & Column_J the gid value of that specific tab; which the formula uses to process the output

